# Getting daily counts for events that don't happen every day

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have a **customer** table in which a new row is inserted when a customer signup occurs.

**Problem**

I want to know the total number of signup per day for a given date range.

For example, find the total number of signup each day from 2015-07-01 to 2015-07-10

**customer table**
sample data [relevant columns shown]

```
customerid    username    created
1             mrbean      2015-06-01
2             tom         2015-07-01
3             jerry       2015-07-01
4             bond        2015-07-02
5             superman    2015-07-10
6             tintin      2015-08-01
7             batman      2015-08-01
8             joker       2015-08-01
```

**Required Output**

```
created      signup
2015-07-01   2
2015-07-02   1
2015-07-03   0
2015-07-04   0
2015-07-05   0
2015-07-06   0
2015-07-07   0
2015-07-08   0
2015-07-09   0
2015-07-10   1
```

**Query used**

```
SELECT 
    DATE(created) AS created, COUNT(1) AS signup
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    DATE(created) BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-10'
GROUP BY DATE(created)
ORDER BY DATE(created)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
created      signup
2015-07-01   2
2015-07-02   1
2015-07-10   1
```

What modification should I make in the query to get the required output?

Comment: I think you just need to change your query code to COUNT(created) As SignUp

Comment: @DavyC still getting the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2157282/1920758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a way to get all the days listed, even those days that aren't represented in your `customer` table. This is a notorious pain in the neck in SQL.  That's because in its pure form SQL lacks the concept of a contiguous sequence of anything ... cardinal numbers, days, whatever.

So, you need to introduce a table containing a source of contiguous cardinal numbers, or dates, or something, and then LEFT JOIN your existing data to that table.

There are a few ways of doing that. One is to create yourself a `calendar` table with a row for every day in the present decade or century or whatever, then join to it. (That table won't be very big compared to the capability of a modern database.

Let's say you have that table, and it has a column named `date`.  Then you'd do this.

```
 SELECT calendar.date AS created,
        ISNULL(a.customer_count, 0) AS customer_count
   FROM calendar
   LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS customer_count,
                   DATE(created) AS created
              FROM customer
             GROUP BY DATE(created)
        ) a ON calendar.date = a.created
   WHERE calendar.date BETWEEN start AND finish 
   ORDER BY calendar.date
```

Notice a couple of things.  First, the `LEFT JOIN` from the calendar table to your data set.  If you use an ordinary `JOIN` the missing data in your data set will suppress the rows from the calendar.

Second, the `ISNULL` in the toplevel `SELECT` to turn the missing, null, values from your dataset into zero values.

Now, you ask, where can I get that calendar table?  I respectfully suggest you look that up, and ask another question if you can't figure it out.

I wrote a little essay on this, which you can find here.http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#c6056)

Create teble with calendar and join it in your query.

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2015-07-01',
        @MaxDate DATE = '2015-07-10';

Create Table tblTempDates 
(created date, signup int)

insert into tblTempDates
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate),  0 As Signup
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;

Create Table tblTempQueryDates
(created date, signup int)

INSERT INTO tblTempQueryDates
SELECT 
    created AS created, COUNT(scandate) AS signup
FROM
    customer
WHERE
    created BETWEEN @MinDate AND @MaxDate
GROUP BY created

UPDATE    tblTempDates
SET  tblTempDates.signup = tblTempQueryDates.signup            
FROM         tblTempDates INNER JOIN
                      tblTempQueryDates ON tblTempDates.created = tblTempQueryDates.created

select * from tblTempDates
order by created

Drop Table tblTempDates
Drop Table tblTempQueryDates
```

Not pretty, but it gives you what you want.